# in my Spring Application,i want to update record in data base and see this : hibernate could not resolve property

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I need to update the record in the database and try use this code, but i see this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: company_id_active of: account.User [update account.User h set h.company_id_active =: ActiveCompanyId where h.user_id =:userId]`

User.java

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id_active")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Company companyActive;
    ...
    Geter,Seter
```

UserRepositoryImpl.java

```
public boolean updateActiveCompanyID(int userId, int ActiveCompanyId) {
        try {


            String SQL= "update User h set h.company_id_active =: ActiveCompanyId where h.user_id =:userId";

            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(SQL);
            query.setParameter("ActiveCompanyId", ActiveCompanyId);
            query.setParameter("userId", userId);
            query.executeUpdate();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MyLogger.logException(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Home.java

```
....
userRepository.updateActiveCompanyID(49,11);
....
```

Comment: You are mixing SQL and HQL. either execute a sql query `createSqlQuery` or use a proper HQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by `entityManager.createQuery(SQL)` you are creating a HQL query and not native query you should use field name corresponding to the definition in the **user class**. so instead of using `company_id_active` in your query string, you should use **companyActive** as :

`String SQL= "update User h set h.companyActive= :ActiveCompanyId where h.user_id =:userId";`

- > And also make sure user_id is also your field name in the class.